# Get specific key of a nested iterable and check if its value exists in a list

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, string-matching

I am trying to access a specific key in a nest dictionary, then match its value to a string in a list. If the string in the list contains the string in the dictionary value, I want to override the dictionary value with the list value. below is an example.

```
my_list = ['string1~', 'string2~', 'string3~', 'string4~', 'string5~', 'string6~']
my_iterable = {'A':'xyz', 
               'B':'string6', 
               'C':[{'B':'string4', 'D':'123'}], 
               'E':[{'F':'321', 'B':'string1'}], 
               'G':'jkl'
               }
```

The key I'm looking for is `B`, the objective is to override `string6` with `string6~`, `string4` with `string4~`, and so on for all `B` keys found in the `my_iterable`.

I have written a function to compute the Levenshtein distance between two strings, but I am struggling to write an efficient ways to override the values of the keys.

```
def find_and_replace(key, dictionary, original_list):
    for k, v in dictionary.items():
        if k == key:
            #function to check if original_list item contains v
            yield v
        elif isinstance(v, dict):
            for result in find_and_replace(key, v, name_list):
                yield result
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            for d in v:
                if isinstance(d, dict):
                    for result in find_and_replace(key, d, name_list):
                        yield result
```

if I call

```
updated_dict = find_and_replace('B', my_iterable, my_list)
```

I want `updated_dict` to return the below:

```
{'A':'xyz', 
 'B':'string6~', 
 'C':[{'B':'string4~', 'D':'123'}], 
 'E':[{'F':'321', 'B':'string1~'}], 
 'G':'jkl'
}
```

Is this the right approach to the most efficient solution, and how can I modify it to return a dictionary with the updated values for `B`?

Comment: Why you have similar keys in your `dict`?

Comment: Added by mistake when I was writing the question. Edited the question to remove duplicate key.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code. I have assumed the structure of input dict to be same throughout the execution.

```
# Input List
my_list = ['string1~', 'string2~', 'string3~', 'string4~', 'string5~', 'string6~']

# Input Dict
# Removed duplicate key "B" from the dict
my_iterable = {'A':'xyz', 
               'B':'string6', 
               'C':[{'B':'string4', 'D':'123'}], 
               'E':[{'F':'321', 'B':'string1'}], 
               'G':'jkl',
               }

# setting search key
search_key = "B"

# Main code
for i, v in my_iterable.items():
    if i == search_key:
        if not isinstance(v,list):
            search_in_list = [i for i in my_list if v in i]
            if search_in_list:
                my_iterable[i] = search_in_list[0]
    else:
        try:
            for j, k in v[0].items():
                if j == search_key:
                    search_in_list = [l for l in my_list if k in l]
                    if search_in_list:
                        v[0][j] = search_in_list[0]
        except:
            continue

# print output
print (my_iterable)
# Result -> {'A': 'xyz', 'B': 'string6~', 'C': [{'B': 'string4~', 'D': '123'}], 'E': [{'F': '321', 'B': 'string1~'}], 'G': 'jkl'}
```

> Above can has scope of optimization using list comprehension or using
>   a function

I hope this helps and counts!

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, if your nesting is kind of complex you can treat the dictionary like a json string and do all sorts of replacements. Its probably not what people would call very pythonic, but gives you a little more flexibility.

```
import re, json

my_list = ['string1~', 'string2~', 'string3~', 'string4~', 'string5~', 'string6~']
my_iterable = {'A':'xyz', 
               'B':'string6', 
               'C':[{'B':'string4', 'D':'123'}], 
               'E':[{'F':'321', 'B':'string1'}], 
               'G':'jkl'}

json_str = json.dumps(my_iterable, ensure_ascii=False)
for val in my_list:
    json_str = re.sub(re.compile(f"""("[B]":\\W?")({val[:-1]})(")"""), r"\1" + val + r"\3", json_str)
my_iterable = json.loads(json_str)
print(my_iterable)
```